# Open URL FileMaker Server Script

Tags: url, server, filemaker, openurl

I desperately need a way to open a URL on an automated server script, the script in question moves my files to the correct place, I then need to hit a URL which will trigger an API to grab my file. I have everything working perfect but the final step, I'm aware that OpenURL does not work on the server, and I have tried and failed using the `BE_OpenURL` step as nothing seems to happen.

I should add that I don't necessarily need a browser to open as such, I just need a URL to be hit in order to kick start my API, as this is a server side script it will be unmanned/autonomous.

Any suggestions what so ever? I am not interested at a system level solution, as I know how to do that already, and also defeats the purpose of this task.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to hit an URL, you can use the Insert from URL script step which is server compatible.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the URL doesnt get hit and I get a Scripting Error (3) when running on the server with the Insert From URL step, yet when I disable this step I dont get the error? Confusing.

Comment: Make sure that “Perform without dialog” is checked, as that option is not server compatible. You can switch your whole script to server compatibility mode to see if everything is right. Also, check the variable/field attached to Insert from Url. After execution it should contain the server response, if any.